# Delete one of many from Array

Tags: ruby

I have an Array that contains some elements multiple times. Now I want to create a new Array with one of those elements deleted.

Example:

```
a = [1,1,1,2]
delete_index = a.find_index(1)
result = a.clone
result.delete_at(delete_index)
# result is now [1,1,2]
```

This code looks really ugly for such an easy task. I had a look at the methods that Array provides, but couldn't find a better way of doing this.

Comment: And for `a = [1,1,1,2]` the result should be `[1,1,2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could monkey patch Array:

```
class Array
  def delete_first_occurrence(o)
    delete_at(find_index(o) || length)
    self
  end
end

a = [1,1,1,2]
result = a.clone.delete_first_occurrence(1)
 => [1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: You probably want to safeguard that: `a.clone.delete_first_occurrence(3) #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer`

Comment: @Michael Kohl - Thank you sir. Added safeguard as per davidcelis above.

Answer (score 2):

```
a.delete_at(a.index(1) || a.length)
```

`a.length` handles the case where your element isn't found; because it's out of range, nothing will be deleted and your return value wil be `nil`.

If part of your question was to do this to a copy of the array, just call it on a `clone`:

```
a2 = a.clone ; a2.delete_at(...)
```

If you want to do this for each duplicated element, you can chain it to a block that selects the duplicated elements:

```
a.select { |e| array.count(e) > 1 }.each { |dup| a.delete_at a.index(dup) }
```

Comment: chaining a clone does not work as delete_at returns what it deleted and not the rest of the array.

Comment: Good point. Edited with a way to keep track of the copied array

Comment: Note that the third solution is O(n^2), which will perform extremely poorly for larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell, but it sounds like you're just trying to remove duplicates from the array. If that's the case, it's as easy as `array.uniq`, which will return a new array with all duplicates removed. If you'd like to modify the original array in place, you can use `array.uniq!` instead.

If that's not what you're trying to accomplish, please update your question with some example input and output of what you're trying to accomplish.